# Translating a rectangle's coordinates

Tags: geometry, translation

I have two applications, one that creates a rectangle, and output's it's left,top,width,height and rotation angle, and another that draws the rectangle to the screen.

Application1 (writer) uses the top, left as the origin for rotation.

Application2 (reader) uses the center as the origin for rotation.

I'm trying to get a deltaX, and deltaY so that I can draw the rectangle, rotate it about the origina, and use a built in translate method, to shift the rectangle into position.

I know that a points rotation can be calculated as follows:

`x' = x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta)`
`y' = x+sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)`

But, with that, I can't seem to figure out the actual delta values needed for the translate method.

In the image below, the white rectangle is drawn using top/left as the rotation point, while the green rectangle is drawn using center as the rotation point. I'd like to shift the green rectangle onto the white one.

(0,0)

[image]

Comment: translate, like, adding the deltas to the rectangle bounds?  or you are talking about some other translation?

Comment: My understanding is translate means moving each coordinates by deltaX,deltaY.

Comment: So application 2 describes rectangles by their center coordinate, width, height and rotation?

Comment: @Alan: and what are the directions of the x- and y-axis in application 1 and 2?

Comment: In both applications, 0,0 is the top,left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to translate by:

[image: (Tx, Ty) = (-w/2 (1-cos theta) - h/2 sin theta), -h/2 (1-cos theta) - w/2 sin theta)]

Development:

- In application 1, the top left vertex of a rectangle shall be  [image: (x1, y1)].
- Since application 1 rotates rectangles about the top left vertex, their rotated position coincides: [image: (x1',y1') = (x1,y1)]
- Application 2 uses center coordinates, which relate to top-left point in application 1 as follows: [image: (xc2,yc2) = (x1,y1) + (w/2,h/2)]
- To calculate the **rotated** top-left vertex in application 2, we apply the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) **R**:[image: (x2',y2') = (xc2,yc2) - R (w/2,h/2)]
- So the translation vector **T** is (substituting equations above): [image]

Comment: Hi Daniel: +1 for the answer as the question was originally written, however I've re-written the question to be more clear. Both rectangles use top,left as their starting point; it's the rotation point that differs. So the white rectangle is rotated about top-left, while the green is rotated from the center.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this issue. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain how you solved this?

Comment: I wish I had 4 accounts. So I could give this answer four votes up!